# Woocommerce SFTP Download link not appear in email after complete purchase

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Problem**

While purchase digital products the download link is not list in email and order complete page.

**My Analysis**

I have completed one e-commerce application using woocommerce. Previously the site was on http:// with FTP and working well. Now site is shifted on live environment. site has SFTP now.

Orders are not saved into _woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions table. But while http:// order saved into this table.

I have checked the apache logs and it shows this type of error log.

```
Cline denied by server configuration /var/www/html/site/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2017/09/file.pdf
```

Are there any file configurations that i missed?

However this is perfectly work for the Debit card transaction but not work for the paypal. i have asked to paypal that i missed any confugration accrding to woorocmmerce documentation, they told me configuration in paypal are correct. 
IPN and PDT (payment data transfer).

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, please consider adding more detail. Have you spoken to your host regarding the issue? Error message speaks for itself really...

Comment: @MatthewB i have not talked i will talk and let you know.

Comment: There was no issues with server, they checked everything.